# How to write python program to Combine second letters of the two strings using reduce()

Tags: python, python-3.x, functools

## Combine second letters of the two strings in the following using reduce().

`string1 = [‘Hello’,’Bye’]`

#### output should be `‘ey’`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for that:

```
from functools import *

string1 = ['Hello','Bye']
print (reduce(lambda a,b : a+b,(i[1] for i in string1)))
```

Output:

```
ey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

string1 = ['Hello','Bye']
comparision = lambda x, y: x[1] + y[1]
print(reduce(comparision, string1))
```

O/P:- `ey`